# How to zoom and translate to center of force directed graph in D3

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I am looking for a method to apply zoom-to-fit to a force directed graph. I already have the ability to zoom in/out to cover a graph on the view screen. I am not sure about the translation to the center of a force directed graph. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using the zoom behavior to fit the graph in the screen it should not be hard to translate using the same behavior. Finding the center is a little tricker, but for a force directed layout you can probably get away with computing the centroid for the graph - just average all the x and y coordinates of your nodes.

Comment: calculateTranslation: function(x,y){
  // get the scale
  var scale = Graph.Zoompos;
  // calculate the centers depending on the scale and viewport
        var scaledCenterX = (Graph.width / scale) / 2;
        var scaledCenterY = (Graph.height / scale) / 2;        
        // calculate the translation vectors
        var panx = -(x - scaledCenterX);
        var pany = -(y - scaledCenterY);
        console.log(panx+" "+pany);
        // set the translation vectors and the scale
  d3.zoom.translate([panx, pany]);
 }